# How to Fill Respective data in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Currently I am working on one of the Warehouse Report Automation. Report that I am receiving from Warehouse contains two Columns Order Ref and Equipment Name which is in given Format.

| Order Ref | EQPT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 10-3423AC | NA |
| 10-3423AC | NA |
| 10-3423AC | PQLR22334 |
| 10-3423AC | NA |
| 10-3410AC | NCRE267 |
| 10-3410AC | NA |
| 10-3410AC | NA |
| 10-3410AC | NA |

I want to Replace NA with Correct EQPT_Name as Per Order Ref using Python Pandas DataFrame

Output

| Order Ref | EQPT_NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 10-3423AC | PQLR22334 |
| 10-3423AC | PQLR22334 |
| 10-3423AC | PQLR22334 |
| 10-3423AC | PQLR22334 |
| 10-3410AC | NCRE267 |
| 10-3410AC | NCRE267 |
| 10-3410AC | NCRE267 |
| 10-3410AC | NCRE267 |

Answer (score 0):

For each `Order Ref`, get the first valid value from `EQPT_NAME` then broadcast this value to all rows of the group:

```
df['EQPT_NAME'] = df.groupby('Order Ref')['EQPT_NAME'].transform('first')
print(df)

# Output
   Order Ref  EQPT_NAME
0  10-3423AC  PQLR22334
1  10-3423AC  PQLR22334
2  10-3423AC  PQLR22334
3  10-3423AC  PQLR22334
4  10-3410AC    NCRE267
5  10-3410AC    NCRE267
6  10-3410AC    NCRE267
7  10-3410AC    NCRE267
```